# PHP ext-intl * extension installation issue for Cakephp 3.0 on OSX Yosmite

Tags: php, cakephp, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install cakephp 3.0 using composer on MAC OSX Yosmite.

But when I run these command line on terminal:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/CakeBake
```

### php composer.phar create-project cakephp/app

I encounter following errors :

> ```
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.1.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
> - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.0, 3.0.0-RC1, 3.0.0-RC2, 3.0.0-alpha1,
> 3.0.0-alpha2, 3.0.0-beta1, 3.0.0-beta2, 3.0.0-beta3, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.1.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev].
> ```

I have already activated : extension=php_intl.dll and also added extension=intl.so to my php.ini in XAMPP/etc/php.ini.

Php version on my computer is php 5.6.8 and XAMPP 5.6.8-0. 
Note: I believed I have installed intl extension through the terminal using ICU libraries.(I am not sure if its the right way to put it. I am very new to all these thing). But It still giving me this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I provided enough information.

Comment: Have you installed the `extension` before activating it??

Comment: yes i have done the installation through the terminal and then i changed the php.ini file. But I doubt that i installed these extension in the right location and that XAMPP can't find these extension? (excuse me if it dosen't make sense.I am very new to all of this)

Comment: MacOSx has already PHP which is different from one XAMPP has, When you run composer it is using php it has on default, you will need to make sure that console uses php of XAMPP for that check http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/getting-command-line-access-php-and-mysql-running-mamp-osx

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable extension=php_intl.dll in your php.ini